# Callback not being called

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dependency-injection, tdd

So I have the following implementation of an interface / method:

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    public T Get<T>(string cacheId, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        var cacheExpiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120);

        var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item, null, cacheExpiry, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to unit test (NUnit / Moq) that given an empty cache (of type Whatever) that

```
<Whatever> Callback
```

the callback is called once; given mock instances of Cache service and the service containing the callback.

The real body of the method pretty much looks like this

```
return _services.Cache.GetBy("CacheKey", () => Callback("argumentsHere"));
```

However what happens instead, is that it refuses to call the callback (tested by the test passing if I do this instead)

```
return Callback("argumentsHere");
```

p.s. I set up the test like so

```
ICacheService cache = null;
_mockDomainServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(cache);
```

but if instead I set it up with a "real" CacheService

```
ICacheService cache = new CacheService();
_mockDomainServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(cache);
```

it works, but is more of an integration test?

Comment: Are you sure that item is null?

Comment: @AlexRiabov yeah I do             

    ICacheService cache = null;
    _mockDomainServiceProvider.Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(cache);

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills I will try how should I share as to offer more than I have will likely need a project / files?

Comment: Ok @mjwills I understand you don't want all of the code, so can you tell me what info is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used mock so don't have know the ins and outs of how it handles parameters when mocking but you could do something like this to get around your problem.

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    public T Get<T>(string cacheId, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        var cacheExpiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120);

        var item = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(cacheId) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheId, item, null, cacheExpiry, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return item;
    }

    protected virtual InsertCache(string key, Object value, CacheDependency dependencies, 
                           DateTime absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration) {
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, dependencies, absoluteExpiration, 
                     Cache.slidingExpiration);
    }
}
```

Do the same with the calls to get the cacheExpiry and the Item and now in your test you can create a MockCacheService that overrides your CacheService with public properties that are used to return cacheExpiry and item from the overriden protected functions. Now you have got full control of your dependencies. Just another way of skinning the cat.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew edited: I see what you mean now, that might be the answer but it feels wrong based on my understanding this should work as is and I'm looking for why it doesnt

Comment: @ScrambledHeads, the fact that you have mocked the function that accepts the callback means that you will never reach the line of code that executes the callback as you are now not entering that function at all.

Comment: I've marked it as the answer as that is clearly whats happening and I guess is my misunderstanding thanks